# Package for creating installation manual?

Tags: documentation

I want to create a installation manual for users. My general structure is, that i want separated steps and at each step I want on the left an image/screenshot and and on the right column a description. Are there any packages which are helpful for this? Or do I have to build it by my own.

Example:

```
Section

Image  Descrption


Section

Image  Descrption

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
First of all, to use \TeX\ or \LaTeX, you have to install a \TeX\ distribution.
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
Next, you need an editor. In MiK\TeX, there is already one called TeXworks, but you can install other editors if you want. I am using VS Code.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Doing like that is painful, so we should have a macro for it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newenvironment{yourenv}[1]
{%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{#1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
}{%
\end{minipage}\ignorespacesafterend
}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\begin{yourenv}{example-image-a}
First of all, to use \TeX\ or \LaTeX, you have to install a \TeX\ distribution.
\end{yourenv}
\end{document}
```

[image]